# Unable to align items to the left in React Navigation (iOS)

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm am trying to get the title, where it says "PersonB, last here recently", to align to the left. It works fine on Android without any explicit styling, but on iOS, I've tried `alignItems: 'flex-start'` as well as with `alignSelf` and `alignContent`, but it doesn't move, it stays in the middle like this:

[image: img]

How can I get it to align to the left?

Here's the relevant code:

```
  const CustomHeader = ({ title, subtitle }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{subtitle}</Text>
    </View>
  );

} else if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    return {
      headerTitle: (
        <View style={{ alignContent: "flex-start" }}>
          <CustomHeader
            title={username}
            subtitle={'last here recently'}
          />
        </View>
      ),
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#000000"
      },
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
      },
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since you mentioned `React Navigation`, I assume you are setting `CustomHeader` as the title component of the stock react-navigation header? If so, the outer title container has a fixed width that does not extend all the way to the left and right buttons. I need to dig up how I solved this in my app and then post it as an answer.

Comment: As the `headerTitle` component and yes, thank you! Not the title (obviously), the headerTitle :D

Comment: check headerTitleAlign out

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a thing in React Navigation. Can you please link to any docs?

Comment: I'm not sure which API or version you're using. Could you provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After react-navigation v2, [headerLayoutPreset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig) was introduced.

```
const CustomStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Main }
  },
  { headerLayoutPreset: 'left' }
);
```

Comment: That overlaps with my back button on iOS (and I assume Android, can't test atm). Is adding `paddingLeft` the only solution?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: You could make a custom HeaderBackButton component, if you want the title displayed as a button label

Comment: [Header button documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html)

Comment: Yup, I have a custom `headerLeft` set to render a `TouchableOpacity` wrapper of the back button. After adding `headerLayoutPreset: 'left'`, the text overlaps the back button.

Comment: Then just add text to the `TouchableOpacity` and remove headerLayoutPreset: 'left'.

Comment: `headerLayourPreset: 'left'` doesn't work on iOS :(